# onActivityResult for PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, notificationmanager

**How do i get the result of an activity started from NotificationManager?**

In other words i need to get the resultCode from a PendingIntent.

```
public void test(Context context){
    Notification notification = new Notification(null, "text", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "text", "text", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

I want to be notified when the browser's activity ends.

> OBS: This code is outside an activity, that's why it recieves the
>   context as parameter

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have activity `A` that sets `PendingIntent`. This `PendingIntent` calls activity `B`. You want receive result of `B`.

You can do this by introducing proxy activity: `A` -> `PendingIntent` -> `ProxyActivity` --> `startActivityForResult` --> `B`. This way you'll receive result from `B` into your `ProxyActivity` activity.

*Note that you should call `startActivityForResult()` in `ProxyActivity.onCreate()`.*

Comment: Thank you inazaruk! I think it will work, but i hope something more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see in simply way , 
IN Activity A :

```
intet.putStringExtra("from notification") ;
```

In Activity B:

```
if (getintent().getStringExtra("from notification") !=null ){
//TODO do what u want !
}
```